# which version of 'adal' module is supported in python 2.7.15?

Tags: python-2.7, adal, azure-function-app

I am trying to deploy a python code to Azure Function (Runtime version:- 1.0.13021.0) where python version is 2.7.15.

I am using a python module `adal` . i have mentioned `adal` in my `requirement.txt` file to get installed in Azure.
But while running function i am getting error, `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'adal'`
In `requirement.txt` i tried with below version of adal also but same error in every case,

```
adal == 0.5.1
adal == 1.2.0
adal == 1.2.1
adal == 1.2.3
```

Can you please let me know which version of `'adal'` module is supported in python 2.7.15 ?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for Azure Functions in Python says that if the package you want to use is not available to their tools, you can include the package in your source bundle under the .python_packages subdirectory of the app folder. Please see the section on custom dependencies: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#custom-dependencies